# How to activate the kitten mode in OpenERP? What is its use?

Tags: odoo

What steps are mandatory if i want to activate the kitten mode inside my openerp server ? Do I have to modify the existing code or I have to use the GUI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the kitten=1 parameter in the url.

```
Example: http://localhost:8069?db=yourdb&kitten=1
```

Comment: This answer is not complete.  What is its use?

Comment: It is useful for showing cat in back ground. And make your background with cat as if you like to see the cats.
Kitten Mode features in OpenERP 7.0:
> Unified Kitten background with optimized transparency for a better kitten mode pleasure
> Hypnotic head-turning loading kitten

Answer (score 1):

One can enable the mode with just "kitten" or "kitten=ANYTHING"

Example:

- `localhost:8069/?kitten`
- `localhost:8069/?kitten=1`
- `localhost:8069/?kitten=0`
- `localhost:8069/?kitten=true`
- `localhost:8069/?kitten=false`
- `localhost:8069/?kitten=show`
- `localhost:8069/?kitten=love`

the code for this is found in a javascript file located

**/web/static/src/js/chrome.js** somewhere around line 1250

the CSS is found at

**/web/static/src/css/base.css** around line 3100